# How to use TensorFlow's C++Api with VisualStudio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tensorflow

I am looking for a way to build and run Tensorflow C++Api on VisualStudio (Windows).

I know how to install and run the Tensorflow C library.
But I could not figure out how to install the C++ library with Api reference.
I wish there was a way to complete this in VisualStudio, preferably without using Bazel or Cmake...

I'm a novice programmer so I could be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not a 1.00 version [Tensorflow.Net](https://tensorflownet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HelloWorld.html).

Use a bit of time, trying to use c++ constant directly to see that they missing some target compatible and array entering points, the link provides you an easy method.

Comment: The question is about C++, not C# or .NET, again you are not answering what was asked.

Comment: It is C++ Tensorflow only interfaces with .NET you can see those C++ methods.

Comment: No. C# is not C++.